# SVG rendering issue in Android Browser

Tags: android, html, css, svg

In the default Android Browser for older Android versions (4.1, maybe 4.2/4.3 [It is on the Android device of a customer, i'm not exactly sure which version he uses]) SVG sprites are not rendered correctly.
Instead of showing the correct clipping with the correct size, the browser shows a smaller version of the image, showing the whole sprite, like in the screenshot below (Android Browser 4.1):

Android screenshot (false rendering)[image]

it should look like this:

Android screenshot (correct rendering)
[image]

Here's the CSS for the sprites:

```
.sprite {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('img/sprite.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1000px 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: transparent !important;
}

.sprite.logo {
  width: 270px;
  height: 55px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  display: block;
}

[...]
```

Every other Browser (including Android Browser 4.4) shows everything correctly.

Comment: SVG was not fully supported until Android 4.4 (and effects/filters are only partially supported): http://caniuse.com/#search=svg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue exists on Android 4.3- and IE9. To solve this, simply specify `width` and `height` attributes for `svg` tag in you file.